# Present another view immediately after dismissal

Tags: swift, homekit

In HomeKit, [HMHome addAccessory()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/homekit/hmhome/1620216-addaccessory?language=objc) seem to present a controller of its own.

```
home.addAccessory(accessory) { error in
    if let error = error {
    else {
       // present another view controller at this point
    }
}
```

When completion handler is called everything should be done. But it doesn't seem like the controller has already been dismissed at that point.

If I tried to present a new controller immediately at the completion, nothing happens. Right now I seem to need to wait for some time before presenting a new controller, but that doesn't seem acceptable.

Is there anything I can do to queue up that operation?

If not, I guess I'll just have to present my next view with empty fields without animation before I try to add the accessory, and then fill in the information after the accessory has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a view controller ?

In swift if you are in [view controller](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller) to present another view controller your can use [present](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present)

So you can write :

```
present(yourViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Yes I know how to present it. The problem in this situation, I have to wait like 3 seconds to present it. I don't want user to see a view I intend to hide.

Comment: Oh I understand, this is the fault of HomeKit ?

Comment: It has to do with how `addAccessory()` call is very peculiar. because it presents a view controller itself, and dismiss it afterward. And I have problem presenting another view controller right after its dismissal.

Comment: I don't see how firmware has to do with it. It's the view and ViewController issue. Actually HomeKit may not has to do with it specifically. Anything that present an UI might exhibit similar behavior.